# Find element created after JS loaded

Tags: jquery

I have the following function:

```
$('#registerButton button').click(function() {
    register();
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your code will work as you require already, so long as the `button` click event is raised after the `.g-recaptcha .rc-anchor-normal` element is added to the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use delegated events via on() if you want events to be handled on dynamically added elements:

```
$(document).on("click", "#registerButton button",function() {
 $('input, select').removeClass('genericInputError');
    $('.statusMessage').text('').hide();
    $('.ajaxLoading').show();
    $('.g-recaptcha .rc-anchor-normal').addClass('recaptchaError');
});
```

Comment: It will behave similar as "#registerButton button" is already present in the dom.